# Redo, redraw and undo on drawing lines, curves, rectangles and ellipse not working properly

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have trouble making a simple drawing GUI work using pyqt.
I'm able to draw rectangles, ellipses, (straight) lines, and curves but I would like to implement a redraw, redo, and clear button as well.

Redraw should be redrawing the scene after undo or redo is pressed.
Undo should erase the last item put on the scene, and if clicked multiple times, undoing each item on the scene accordingly. Redo should do the opposite.

Sometimes, mostly in the beginning, it tends to work but after having clear the scene, the buttons aren't working as intended.

Here's my code:

```
import sys
from CRectangle import CRectangle
from CElipse import CElipse
from CLine import CLine
from CDraw import CDraw

from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QColorDialog, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType("draw.ui")


class MyApp(QMainWindow, QBrush, QPen, Qt):
    def __init__(self):
        self._cleared = "blanc"
        self._undone = 0
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self._scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.ui.GraphicView.setScene(self._scene)
        self._scene.setSceneRect(80, 60, 600, 400)
        self._brush = QBrush(Qt.black, Qt.SolidPattern)
        self._pen = QPen(Qt.black)
        self._items = []
        self._shape = "Rect"

        self.ui.GraphicView.mousePressEvent = self.mousePressEvent
        self.ui.GraphicView.mouseMoveEvent = self.mouseMoveEvent
        self.ui.GraphicView.mouseReleaseEvent = self.mouseReleaseEvent

        self.ui.btnUndo.clicked.connect(self.btnUndopressed)
        self.ui.btnRedo.clicked.connect(self.btnRedopressed)
        self.ui.btnClear.clicked.connect(self.btnClearpressed)
        self.ui.btnRedraw.clicked.connect(self.btnRedrawpressed)

        self.ui.btnRect.clicked.connect(self.btnRectpressed)
        self.ui.btnEllipse.clicked.connect(self.btnEllipsepressed)
        self.ui.btnLine.clicked.connect(self.btnLinepressed)
        self.ui.btnDraw.clicked.connect(self.btnDrawpressed)

        self.ui.btnColor.clicked.connect(self.btnColorPressed)

    def btnClearpressed(self):
        self._scene.clear()
        self._cleared = "cleared"

    def btnRedrawpressed(self):
        self._scene.clear()
        for value in self._items:
            self.drawevent(value)
        self._cleared = "blanc"

    def btnUndopressed(self):
        self._scene.clear()
        self._undone -= 1
        if self._undone != 0:
            for value in self._items[0:(self._undone)]:
                self.drawevent(value)
        if self._undone == 0:
            for value in self._items[0:-1]:
                self.drawevent(value)

        self._cleared = "undo"

    def btnRedopressed(self):
        self._scene.clear()
        self._undone += 1
        if self._undone != 0:
            for value in self._items[0:(self._undone)]:
                self.drawevent(value)
        if self._undone == 0:
            for value in self._items:
                self.drawevent(value)

        self._cleared = "blanc"

    def btnColorPressed(self):
        color = QColorDialog.getColor()
        if color.isValid():
            self.pen_color = color

        self._brush = QBrush(color)
        self._pen = QPen(color)

    def btnRectpressed(self):
        self._shape = "Rect"

    def btnEllipsepressed(self):
        self._shape = "Elipse"

    def btnLinepressed(self):
        self._shape = "Line"

    def btnDrawpressed(self):
        self._shape = "Draw"

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        point = self.ui.GraphicView.mapToScene(event.pos())
        x = point.x()
        y = point.y()
        if self._shape == "Rect":
            self._figure = CRectangle(x, y)
        elif self._shape == "Ellipse":
            self._figure = CElipse(x, y)
        elif self._shape == "Line":
            self._figure = CLine(x, y)
        elif self._shape == "Draw":
            self.setMouseTracking(True)
            self._figure = CDraw(x, y)

        self._figure.brush = self._brush
        self._figure.pen = self._pen

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self._shape == "Draw":
            point = self.ui.GraphicView.mapToScene(event.pos())
            x = point.x()
            y = point.y()
            self._figure.add(x, y)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        point = self.ui.GraphicView.mapToScene(event.pos())
        x = point.x()
        y = point.y()
        self._figure.add(x, y)

        if self._cleared == "blanc":
            self._items.append(self._figure)
        if self._cleared == "undo":
            self._items[-1] = self._figure
            self._cleared = "blanc"
        if self._cleared == "cleared":
            self._items = []
            self._items.append(self._figure)
            self._cleared = "blank"
        self.drawevent(self._figure)

    def drawevent(self, value):
        item = value.draw()
        if value.shape == "Draw":
            itemx = item[0]
            itemy = item[1]

            for i in range(1, len(itemx) - 1):
                item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsLineItem(itemx[i - 1], itemy[i - 1], itemx[i], itemy[i])
                item.setPen(value.pen)
                self._scene.addItem(item)

        elif value.shape == "Line":
            item.setPen(value.pen)
            self._scene.addItem(item)
        else:
            item.setPen(value.pen)
            item.setBrush(value.brush)
            self._scene.addItem(item)

        self.setMouseTracking(False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = 0
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Class CLine:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class CLine():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    def add(self, x, y):
        self._x2 = x
        self._y2 = y

    def draw(self):
        return QtWidgets.QGraphicsLineItem(self._x, self._y, self._x2, self._y2)

    @property
    def brush(self):
        return self._shapebrush

    @brush.setter
    def brush(self, value):
        self._shapebrush = value

    @property
    def pen(self):
        return self._shapepen

    @pen.setter
    def pen(self, value):
        self._shapepen = value

    @property
    def shape(self):
        return "Line"
```

class CDraw:

```
class CDraw():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._xlist = []
        self._ylist = []
        self._xlist.append(x)
        self._ylist.append(y)

    def add(self, x, y):
        self._xlist.append(x)
        self._ylist.append(y)

    def draw(self):
        if len(self._xlist) > 1:
            return self._xlist, self._ylist

    @property
    def brush(self):
        return self._shapebrush

    @brush.setter
    def brush(self, value):
        self._shapebrush = value

    @property
    def pen(self):
        return self._shapepen

    @pen.setter
    def pen(self, value):
        self._shapepen = value

    @property
    def shape(self):
        return "Draw"
```

Class CEllipse:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class CElipse():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    def add(self, x, y):
        self._width = x - self._x
        self._height = y - self._y

    def draw(self):
        return QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem(self._x, self._y, self._width, self._height)

    @property
    def brush(self):
        return self._shapebrush

    @brush.setter
    def brush(self, value):
        self._shapebrush = value

    @property
    def pen(self):
        return self._shapepen

    @pen.setter
    def pen(self, value):
        self._shapepen = value

    @property
    def shape(self):
        return "Ellipse"
```

class CRectangle:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QBrush
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class CRectangle:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
        self._shapebrush = QBrush(Qt.black, Qt.SolidPattern)
        self._shapepen = QPen(Qt.black)

    def add(self, x, y):
        self._width = x - self._x
        self._height = y - self._y

    def draw(self):
        return QtWidgets.QGraphicsRectItem(self._x, self._y, self._width, self._height)

    @property
    def brush(self):
        return self._shapebrush

    @brush.setter
    def brush(self, value):
        self._shapebrush = value

    @property
    def pen(self):
        return self._shapepen

    @pen.setter
    def pen(self, value):
        self._shapepen = value

    @property
    def shape(self):
        return "Rect"
```

Comment: Is there a way to simplify the example into a smaller section of code that will reproduce the problem. This is quite a lot to digest and understand before we can begin to actually find the error. Additionally without the "draw.ui" file, it is impossible to run the code as-is

Comment: I also agree: your code is more than 300 lines, spread into too many files and still not reproducible. Please reduce it and ensure you provide a proper [mre]: this is not a debugging service, we should focus on the problem, not in trying to recreate it. Also, please explain what you mean by "the buttons aren't working as intended".

Comment: MyApp doesn't need to inherit from QBrush, QPen, and Qt

Comment: @alec good catch, and that's another point for which too extended code in a question is never good, as most people don't even bother to look at it and notice serious errors such as this, as soon as they see how unnecessarily long the code is.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).